# Unable to draw polline on the map in openlayer3 using direction service

Tags: openlayers-3, polyline, direction, osrm

I am trying to add direction service to the map 
1:I need to display the map 
2:once i get the response from the server or invoke the method only then i should draw the poly line i am trying to do it as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>

<script>
    var map;
    var vectorLayer;
    var extentToZoom;
    var geojsonObject;

   /* function addGeoObject(){
        geojsonObject ={"status":200,"hint_data":{"locations":["1DYUCf____89vE8AWwAAANkCAAAAAAAAcAAAAG_vKABaqAAATqcUAIO1MgYAAAEB","1DYUCf____89vE8AEAAAAHAAAADZAgAAAAAAAG_vKABaqAAAtZkUAPGvMgYBAAEB"],"checksum":4294707914},"route_name":["T3 Arrival Drive","T3 Arrival Drive"],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"{srqAewyieEzrExuAtDhA","via_indices":[0,2],"route_instructions":[["10","T3 Arrival Drive",418,0,2,"418m","S",202,1,"N",22],["15","",0,2,0,"0m","N",0,"N",0]],"via_points":[[1.35355,103.986563],[1.350069,103.985137]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"total_distance":418,"total_time":65,"end_point":"T3 Arrival Drive","start_point":"T3 Arrival Drive"}}
        //console.log(geojsonObject.coordinates);
    }*/
    function drawPolyline(geoObject){
    var image = new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: null,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
    });
    var styles = {
        'Point': new ol.style.Style({
            image: image
        }),
        'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'green',
                width: 3
            })
        }),
        'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'green',
                width: 1
            })
        }),
        'MultiPoint': new ol.style.Style({
            image: image
        }),
        'MultiPolygon': new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'yellow',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.1)'
            })
        }),
        'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'blue',
                lineDash: [4],
                width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
            })
        }),
        'GeometryCollection': new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'magenta',
                width: 2
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'magenta'
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 10,
                fill: null,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'magenta'
                })
            })
        }),
        'Circle': new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'red',
                width: 2
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
            })
        })
    };
    var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    };
        geojsonObject =geoObject;
    var routeGeom = new ol.format.Polyline(
            {
                factor: 1e6
            }).readGeometry(geojsonObject.route_geometry, {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
    var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry:routeGeom
    })
     extentToZoom = routeGeom.getExtent();
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [routeFeature]
    });
        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: vectorSource,
                    style: styleFunction
                })
            ],
            target: 'laneMap'
        });
}

    function initMap(){
        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.986908, 1.353199]),
                rotation: 68*Math.PI/180,
                zoom: 18
            })
        });

    }
    initMap();
    geojsonObject ={"status":200,"hint_data":{"locations":["1DYUCf____89vE8AWwAAANkCAAAAAAAAcAAAAG_vKABaqAAATqcUAIO1MgYAAAEB","1DYUCf____89vE8AEAAAAHAAAADZAgAAAAAAAG_vKABaqAAAtZkUAPGvMgYBAAEB"],"checksum":4294707914},"route_name":["T3 Arrival Drive","T3 Arrival Drive"],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"{srqAewyieEzrExuAtDhA","via_indices":[0,2],"route_instructions":[["10","T3 Arrival Drive",418,0,2,"418m","S",202,1,"N",22],["15","",0,2,0,"0m","N",0,"N",0]],"via_points":[[1.35355,103.986563],[1.350069,103.985137]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"total_distance":418,"total_time":65,"end_point":"T3 Arrival Drive","start_point":"T3 Arrival Drive"}};
    drawPolyline(geojsonObject);
   /* var geoobject2={"status":200,"hint_data":{"locations":["UiQkCf____-ljiMAEAAAABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP____-jqAAAt5gUAG2wMgYAAAEB","c8gaCf____8AAAAAMgAAALAAAAAAAAAAHQEAAOviEAajqAAAdqQUABy3MgYAAAEB"],"checksum":4089551480},"route_name":["East Coast Parkway (ECP)",""],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"mjkqAyewieEsHuB_m@qWoYwJuDoDoAqBoFaJkCsD}H_Hai@{Pw`@iM","via_indices":[0,10],"route_instructions":[["10","East Coast Parkway (ECP)",18,0,2,"18m","N",21,1,"S",201],["1","",308,1,24,"307m","NE",28,1,"SW",208],["1","",65,9,5,"65m","NE",23,1,"SW",203],["15","",0,10,0,"0m","N",0,"N",0]],"via_points":[[1.349815,103.985261],[1.352822,103.986972]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"total_distance":391,"total_time":29,"end_point":"","start_point":"East Coast Parkway (ECP)"}};
    drawPolyline(geoobject2);*/
    initMap();
    map.getView().fit(extentToZoom,map.getSize())
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code initMap method will draw the plain map
once i invoke the drawPolyline method it should show the plot (this is because i will get the data from the zmq once i get the data i should plot it )

I tried for a long time doing it please help by posting the correct code to accomplish it or suggest a way to do it

Comment: Vector layers can be loaded in a much simpler way. See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/vector-layer.html. I am posting an answer below which assumes you can call your routing service with an AJAX GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your routing service responds to a simple AJAX GET request, you can save yourself a lot of effort using OpenLayers's built-in layer loading. Something like

```
function drawPolyline(url) {
  map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.Polyline(),
      url: url
    }),
    style: styleFunction
  }));
}
```

The `url` argument in the above function is the url you use to get the track from your routing service.